# System of equation for a math text problem

Tags: systems-of-equations, puzzle

Ive been trying to find the correct system of equation for this one problem for a long time and since i dont want to disturb anyone else in the office with my schoolwork Im posting it here where I could find someno:

There is a coffee merchant who is selling coffee beans. 500g of type ***a*** cost €8.-, 500g of type ***b*** €10.- and 500g of type ***c*** €12.- .

a) A mixture of 500g of each of these types costs €9.- .

Establish an equation for the amount of each type in g and state every solution (***a***,***b***,***c*** ∈]0 ; 1[)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? This is not a site where people do your homework for you

Comment: I tried various systems: a * x/500 = 8, b * x/500 = 10, c * x/500 = 12 and (a+b+c) * x/500 where x would be the amount of gram. I also tried thinking about the type a costing 8 euros per 500g: 8€/500 = a then the system would be like this:  a * 500 = 8, b* 500 = 10, c * 500 = 12 and (a+b+c) * 500 = 9 or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should differentiate between *weight* ($m$) and *price* ($p$). In this problem the prices are given (as per gram), but the weights in the questioned mixture are unknown. You can approach it in the following way.

The costs ($\$$ per gram) are \begin{align}p_{\mathrm{a}}&=\frac{8}{500}\,(\$/\mathrm{g})\\p_{\mathrm{b}}&=\frac{10}{500}\,(\$/\mathrm{g})\\p_{\mathrm{c}}&=\frac{12}{500}\,(\$/\mathrm{g})\end{align}

Now, we know some $500\,\mathrm{g}$ mixture of the described coffee types costs $9\,\$$. Thus, assuming $m_{\mathrm{a}}$, $m_{\mathrm{b}}$ and $m_{\mathrm{c}}$ to be the unknown weights of the coffee types in the mixture, we have $$m_{\mathrm{a}}+m_{\mathrm{b}}+m_{\mathrm{c}}=500\,(\mathrm{g})$$
and since the price of the mixture is given $9\,\$$ we can write $$p_{\mathrm{a}}m_{\mathrm{a}}+p_{\mathrm{b}}m_{\mathrm{b}}+p_{\mathrm{c}}m_{\mathrm{c}}=9\,\$$$

Unfortunately, to solve the problem you'll need one more equation since there are three unknowns $m_{\mathrm{a}}$, $m_{\mathrm{b}}$ and $m_{\mathrm{c}}$ and still two equations.

Comment: I really dont know if yours is correct. I get when I put all these variables into my Ti-nspire cx a similar solution to that in my book. mc becomes λ mb becomes -2λ+125 and ma becomes λ+250. I dont really understand. The solution is here http://imgur.com/a/dJ29O btw

Comment: The $\lambda$ that you're seeing is because the above system of equations has a missing equation and thus the only you could find is a parametric solution; i.e., the solution depends on some parameter, (here $\lambda$ which is taken equal to $m_{\mathrm{c}}$). Note that you can set the parameter to various values, and all answers you'll get will be correct.


In short, you still need one more equation to be done.